# My return statement doesn't return

Tags: java, if-statement, return

Here is my code:

CLASS

```
package work;

public class Run {

    private int sec;
    private int sec2;
    private int sec3;
    private double min;
    private double min2;
    private double min3;
    private String n1;
    private String n2;
    private String n3;


    public Run(int s, int ss, int sss, String n, String nn, String nnn){
        sec = s;
        sec2 = ss;
        sec3 = sss;
        n1 = n;
        n2 = nn;
        n3 = nnn;
        calcMin();
    }


    public void calcMin(){
        min = (double) sec/60;
        min2 = (double) sec2/60;
        min3 = (double) sec3/60;
    }



    public String getres(){
        String res = "";
        if(min>min2 && min>min3 && min2>min3){
            res = n1+n2+n3;
        }
        else if (min>min2 && min>min3 && min2<min3){
            res = n1+n3+n2;
        }
        else if (min2>min && min2>min3 && min>min3){

            res = n2+n1+n3;
        }
        return res;
    }




}
```

MAIN

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("n1");
String ni = x.next(); 
System.out.println("His time in s");
int s1 = x.nextInt();
System.out.println("n2");
String nii = x.next();
System.out.println("His time in s");
int s2 = x.nextInt();
System.out.println("n3");
String niii = x.next();
System.out.println("His time in s");
int s3 = x.nextInt();

Run gogo = new Run(s1, s2, s3, ni, nii, niii);

System.out.println(gogo.getres());
```

In the end, it doesn't show anything, it's blank.
The problem asks the results in minutes of a race.
Like in competition, the one with the lowest time has to be first and etc..
Then, it has to show the name of the first, the second and third according to their time.

The problem is that after the main asks the question, it doesn't show anything.
I know that advanced people would use array list, but I am not allowed to.
I didn't put all the if-else-if statements, because it still doesn't work.
Please help me.

Comment: you said your retrun statments doesn't return ? but are you sure it dont return empty string ???

Comment: I put that String res = n1+n2+n3;  so that it returns those Strings in that order or a specific order for each statements.

Comment: you use " if  " and "  else if " statement , perhaps none of these conditional statements have true result , you can add one "else" statement at the end and check the answer . like :

else
     res = "hi";

Comment: OK, so it returns the else res="hi"; Which means that the conditions aren't fulfilled. Right??

Comment: ok, i found an error, but not the mistake in my codes. Actually, when i put an s3 lower then the s2, it shows me 0 as a result.

Comment: Ok found the problems, I just reversed the > by < since the time has to be lower then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the logic within the conditions for your **IF** statements definitely needs tweaking in order to maintain *First*, *Second*, and *Third* place winners of the entered race times.

Another way you could look at this however is to take all the calculated time values for each racer and sort them in ascending order. The trick here is to have the Names for each racer follow their respective time values as those values are being sorted. You're actually doing this with your **IF** and **ELSE/IF** statements now anyways. Here's another way. Since there are only three racers this can easily be accomplished by declaring and using a couple temporary variables within each **IF** statement code block (one *double* variable and one *String* variable).

Here is an example:

```
// Sort race times and racer names
// to follow their race time...
if (min > min2) {
    double tmpVal = min;
    String tmp = n1;
    min = min2; n1 = n2;
    min2 = tmpVal; n2 = tmp;
}

if (min2 > min3) {
    double tmpVal = min2;
    String tmp = n2;
    min2 = min3; n2 = n3;
    min3 = tmpVal; n3 = tmp;
}

if (min > min2) {
    double tmpVal = min;
    String tmp = n1;
    min = min2; n1 = n2;
    min2 = tmpVal; n2 = tmp;
}

// Display Race Results in console...
System.out.println("The race winners are:");
System.out.println("First Place:\t" + n1 + "\t(in " + min + " minutes)");
System.out.println("Second Place:\t" + n2 + "\t(in " + min2 + " minutes)");
System.out.println("Third Place:\t" + n3 + "\t(in " + min3 + " minutes)");
```

Food for thought I guess.